# Which approach is is better for talking between two process in c?

Tags: c, linux

I have two different applications.I have to inform application_1 from application_2 that application_1 have to do some operation.(should call a function).

1. I can write some message 'take_action' in a text file from application_2 and application_1 will check that text file for 'take_action' on a regular interval.After getting 'take_action' it will call corresponding function and will write 'action_taken' to the text file.
2. I can use pipe or shared memory instead of file.
3. I can pass signal from application_2 through kill command (kill -SIGHUP) and call required function if SIGHUP signal comes to application_1.

Sample code for approach 1 and 3 are as follows.

approach_1:

in application_2:

```
    fprintf(fp, "take_action");
```

in application_1:

```
    int rd = read(filedReading, lineText, 13);
    if (strcmp(lineText, "take_action") == 0)
    {
    reloadRule(); //calling required function
    }
```

approach_3:

in application_2:

```
    system("kill -SIGHUP");
```

in application_1:

```
    void sig_handler(int signo)
    {
    switch(signo) {
    case SIGUSR1:
    opt_debug = opt_debug ? 0 : 1;
    break;
    case SIGHUP:
    log_msg(LOG_NOTICE, "SIGHUP SIGNAL RECEIVED");
    reloadRule(); //calling required function
    default:
    cleanexit(0);
    }
```

Which approach is best for this kind of problem?

Comment: Depends on your needs. You also have net sockets and message queues. Each has slightly different features and strengths. If the message really is nothing more than "Go!", then a signal is probably simplest.

Comment: Another option is some kind of message bus or publish/subscribe framework, such as [dbus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus).

Answer (score 2):

Opinion as always:

A temporary file is almost always the wrong thing to do if only 1 machine is involved, and RPC methods exist if you need multiple machines to cooperate.

When it is easy to establish the handle, anonymous pipes work well. You can use socketpair and mkfifo extend the pipe model to a wider set of scenarios.

Shared memory is the way forward when the pipe bandwidth is an issue. You can get a lot of data down a pipe, but it still involves a number of copies of the memory. Setting up a shared memory pool is a pain, but it gives both processes (almost) direct access to an agreed shared memory area, that is incredibly fast for data transfers. Of course you have to get this set up and there are potential synchronisation issues, but you can use your pipes to easily establish the connection or to synchronise the memory pool at a much lower bandwidth.

Signals are very limiting. You can only easily send a single flag, and they all already have reasons for existing, and what happens when "R" decides to use USR1 and USR2 for memory management, so you can't use your code with "R" programs, etc? Message queues extend signals to have a small payload, of course.

Comment: If I use socket then I have to listen on a socket continuously. Will it not make more overhead than other approaches? I cannot understand 'Shared memory is the way forward when the pipe bandwidth is an issue.'. Would you discuss this line in some detail?

Comment: @Nayan It greatly depend on how you manage your socket : if you poll your socket continuously, yes, it will have overhead, but you can have an another aproach : create a thread that will be dedicated to listen to the socket (the socket should be blocking). this way, the thread will sleep until there is something in the socket. When there is something in the socket, read it and set a flag (like "take_action = true;"). On your "main" thread, do your action when it's convenient for you, using the flag to know if you have to do it. Of course, this is just a draft, you have to adapt it.

Answer (score 1):

If you *can* use an anonymous pipe, then that's probably the best option.

This is because your ability to use a pipe means that your processes instances are intrinsically linked and started together, otherwise it would be hard to open a pipe between them.

If the processes are started together as a pair, they presumably intend to talk to exactly each other and not any other instances of the same programs, and they are probably expected to exit together. Pipes make this very simple, safe, and straight forward.

If the processes were started independently and you wanted to play matchmaker between various instances that weren't started strictly in pairs, then pipes would not have been an option, and sockets would have been a better fit.